# Unity 5.1 and OnGUI()

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I had the following simple code working, before upgrading to Unity 5 but now nothing happens when I press the `Space` key!

```
void OnGUI()
{
    if ( Input.GetKey( KeyCode.Escape ) )
    {
        GUILayout.BeginArea( new Rect(50, 50, 100, 100) );
        GUILayout.Button("Exiting!");
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
}
```

The script is attached to an empty `gameobject`...

Should I change something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code clearly Saying `KeyCode.Escape` and not getting `space` key
change that to `KeyCode.Space` and it'll work

Comment: I'm Glad, then do a favor and mark the correct answer